# Generic type transformations with Shapeless

Tags: scala, generic-programming, shapeless

I currently started to experiment with Shapeless. My first try was the following code example. The Shapeless version is 2.3.0 and Scala version 2.11.7:

```
import org.scalatest._
import shapeless._

sealed trait Dog {
  def favoriteFood: String
}

sealed trait Cat{
  def isCute: Boolean
}

sealed trait Green

sealed trait Blue[G <: Green]{
  def makeGreen(): G = {
    val blueGen = LabelledGeneric[this.type]
    val greenGen = LabelledGeneric[G]
    val blue = blueGen.to(this)
    val green = greenGen.from(blue)
    green
  }
}

case class BlueDog(override val favoriteFood: String) extends Dog with Blue[GreenDog]
case class GreenDog(override val favoriteFood: String) extends Dog with Green

case class GreenCat(override val isCute: Boolean) extends Cat with Green
case class BlueCat(override val isCute: Boolean) extends Cat with Blue[GreenCat]

class ShapelessExperimentsTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers {

  "Make green" should "work" in {
    val blueDog = new BlueDog("Bones")
    val greenDog: GreenDog = blueDog.makeGreen
    assert(greenDog.favoriteFood == "Bones")

    val blueCat = new BlueCat(true)
    val greenCat: GreenCat = blueCat.makeGreen
    assert(greenCat.isCute)
  }
}
```

This code doesn't compile though because I didn't provide values for the implicit parameter lgen for the LabelledGenerics. The compile error therefore is

```
...ShapelessExperimentsTest.scala:16: could not find implicit value for parameter lgen: shapeless.LabelledGeneric[Blue.this.type]
```

and

```
...ShapelessExperimentsTest.scala:17: could not find implicit value for parameter lgen: shapeless.LabelledGeneric[G]
```

My problem is that I couldn't find out the correct way to provide those implicits to make the example work. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I don't think LabelledGeneric is designed or supposed to work with abstract types or singleton types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, in Scala, every "bit of generic
-ness" has to be fixed at invocation site, this basically means that something like:

```
  val blueGen = LabelledGeneric[this.type]
  val greenGen = LabelledGeneric[G]
```

In the body of a function doesn't compile because the compiler can't nail down "this.type" and "G". Luckily, implicits are in the language exactly to solve this problem:

```
def makeGreen[T](implicit blueGen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[this.type, T], greenGen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[G, T]):
```

(Aux is just a pattern to make computations on types, I highly suggest [this](http://gigiigig.github.io/posts/2015/09/13/aux-pattern.html) article if you are not familiar with it)

Again though, this code doesn't compile probably because the compiler can't infere that this.type is actually a case class and can't find an implicit LabelledGeneric instance.

Instead, you can refactor your code to something like this:

```
import org.scalatest._
import shapeless._

sealed trait Animal

sealed trait Dog extends Animal {
  def favoriteFood: String
}

sealed trait Cat extends Animal {
  def isCute: Boolean
}

sealed trait Color
sealed trait Green extends Color
sealed trait Blue extends Color

trait GreenColorable[A <: Animal, G <: Green] {
  def makeGreen[T](animal: A)(implicit animalGen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, T], greenGen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[G, T]): G = {
    val blue = animalGen.to(animal)
    val green = greenGen.from(blue)

    green
  }
}

object Colorables {
  def GreenColorable[A <: Animal, G <: Green] = new GreenColorable[A, G] {}
}

case class BlueDog(override val favoriteFood: String) extends Dog with Blue
case class GreenDog(override val favoriteFood: String) extends Dog with Green

case class GreenCat(override val isCute: Boolean) extends Cat with Green
case class BlueCat(override val isCute: Boolean) extends Cat with Blue

class ShapelessExperimentsTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers {

  "Make green" should "work" in {
    val blueDog = new BlueDog("Bones")
    val greenDogColorable= Colorables.GreenColorable[BlueDog, GreenDog]
    val greenDog = greenDogColorable.makeGreen(blueDog)
    assert(greenDog.favoriteFood == "Bones")

    val blueCat = new BlueCat(true)
    val greenCatColorable = Colorables.GreenColorable[BlueCat, GreenCat]
    val greenCat: GreenCat = greenCatColorable.makeGreen(blueCat)
    assert(greenCat.isCute)
  }
}
```

Here, the actual conversion is moved into a separate typeclass that takes the actual case class input and output types as parameters.